# Rename or create synonym for draw.io (diagrams.net)

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The tool/website https://draw.io has been [renamed/moved](https://www.diagrams.net/blog/move-diagrams-net) to https://diagrams.net. I've submitted an edit for [draw.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw.io). Would the next step be creating the tag [diagrams.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagrams.net) as a synonym or having a moderator rename [draw.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw.io)?

Comment: we have a [tag:diagram] already. I don't expect those get  mixed up. I think the best way to go forward is: create the new tag and then synonym draw.io to the new tag. Let's see what others have to offer.

Comment: I agree with what rene proposed. Just wanted to add that this action will best reflect the "history" of the tag/tool. Old questions will still have `draw.io`, but any new question (even if the user tries to use `draw.io`) will have the new, relevant name `diagrams.net`